# Consultar um registro no SQLite

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, query, sqlite

Estou com um problema para realizar uma consulta em um banco de dados SQLite de uma aplicação android que estou estudando.
Consigo recuperar todos os registros que o banco contém, mas não consigo realizar a busca de um único registro da tabela. Segue o código do banco e da classe que o manipula.

```
public class BancoDeDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String NOME_BD = "JurisIndicium";
private static final int VERSAO_BD = 1;

//variáveis para criação da tabela usuário
public static final String TABELA_USUARIO = "usuario";
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String NOME = "nome";
public static final String OAB = "oab";
public static final String SENHA = "senha";

//variáveis para criação da tabela Processo
public static final String TABELA_PROCESSO = "processo";
public static final String ID_PROCESSO = "_idProcesso";
public static final String N_DO_PROCESSO = "nDoProcesso";
public static final String TIPO_ACAO = "tipoAcao";
public static final String DATA_JULGADO = "dataJulgado";
public static final String N_SPROC = "nSproc";
public static final String PROTOCOLO = "protocolo";
public static final String ORGAO_E_RELATOR = "orgaoRelator";
public static final String REVISOR  = "revisor";
public static final String PROTELANTE  = "protelante";
public static final String REPRESENTANTE_PROTELANTE = "representanteProtelante";
public static final String PROTELADO  = "protelado";
public static final String REPRESENTANTE_PROTELADO = "representanteProtelado";
public static final String TERCEIRO = "terceiro";
public static final String ASSISTENTE = "assistente";
public static final String REPRESENTANTE_JURIDICO = "representanteJuridico";
public static final String MOVIMENTACAO = "movimentacao";
public static final String OBS = "obs";
public static final String INICIO = "inicio";
public static final String FIM = "fim";

public BancoDeDados(Context contexto) {//construtor da classe
    super(contexto, NOME_BD, null, VERSAO_BD);
}

@Override//cria o banco em sua inexistencia e estabelece a conexão
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bd) {

    //bloco de criação da tabela usuário
    bd.execSQL("create table "+TABELA_USUARIO
            +"("+ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +NOME+" text not null, "
            +OAB+" text not null, "
            +SENHA+" text not null);");

    //bloco de criação da tabela processo
    bd.execSQL("create table processo"
            +"("+ID_PROCESSO+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +N_DO_PROCESSO+" text not null, "
            +TIPO_ACAO+" text not null, "
            +DATA_JULGADO+" text not null, "
            +N_SPROC+" text not null, "
            +PROTOCOLO+" text not null, "
            +ORGAO_E_RELATOR+" text not null, "
            +REVISOR+" text not null, "
            +PROTELANTE+" text not null, "
            +REPRESENTANTE_PROTELANTE+" text not null, "
            +PROTELADO+" text not null,"
            +REPRESENTANTE_PROTELADO+" text not null, "
            +TERCEIRO+" text not null, "
            +ASSISTENTE+" text not null, "
            +REPRESENTANTE_JURIDICO+" text not null, "
            +MOVIMENTACAO+" text not null, "
            +OBS+" text not null, "
            +INICIO+" text not null, "
            +FIM+" text not null);");
}

@Override//atualiza o banco ja criado
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase bd, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {//
    bd.execSQL("drop table usuario");
    onCreate(bd);
}
```

}

```
public Processo buscaProcesso(String numeroProcesso){
    Processo processo;
    bd = bdHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = bd.query(BancoDeDados.TABELA_PROCESSO, new String[]{BancoDeDados.TIPO_ACAO,
                    BancoDeDados.PROTELANTE, BancoDeDados.MOVIMENTACAO},
                    BancoDeDados.N_DO_PROCESSO + " = ?", new String[]{numeroProcesso+""},
                    null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToNext();
        processo = new Processo();
        processo.setTipoAcao(cursor.getString(0));
        processo.setProtelante(cursor.getString(1));
        processo.setUltimaMovimentacao(cursor.getString(2));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return processo;

}
```

Desde já agradeço toda ajuda. PS: se cometi algum erro com relação às regras de postagem, por favor me corrijam.

Comment: Rodolfo, qual seria o problema que está tendo? A princípio os únicos problemas que eu vejo são: `cursor` nunca vai ser nulo, o que pode ocorrer é o `moveToNext` retornar false se não houver resultados, recomendo usar um `moveToFirst`, checando o retorno logo no começo. Outra coisa são os índices, o ideal é usar o `getColumnIndexOrThrow(nomeDaColuna)` e não acessar diretamente, a api de persistência do Android não funciona igual ao JDBC :/

Comment: Wakin, obrigado pela resposta. Estou passando uma String como parâmetro para o método buscaProcesso, e estava tentando usá-la para conseguir um registro cujo número do processo fosse igual a esta String. Só consegui retorno ao passar o id do registro. Obrigado.